# TorBrowser connected through Chutney uses real external Tor nodes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bridge

I have setup a Chutney tool successfully and was wondering if I can route my traffic through a Chutney-made network and to the internet. I was going to test that using TorBrowser and providing custom bridge in the browser tor settings.

For the network setup I used:

```
./chutney configure networks/bridges-min
./chutney start networks/bridges-min
```

`./chutney status networks/bridges-min` gives me information about a network made of 7 tor instances:

```
test000a     is running with PID 20520: Tor 0.4.3.5.
test001a     is running with PID 20523: Tor 0.4.3.5.
test002a     is running with PID 20526: Tor 0.4.3.5.
test003ba    is running with PID 20529: Tor 0.4.3.5.
test004r     is running with PID 20535: Tor 0.4.3.5.
test005br    is running with PID 20538: Tor 0.4.3.5.
test006bc    is running with PID 20541: Tor 0.4.3.5.
```

Now, I assumed `test005br` is a bridge. I figured out it's port and provided to the TorBrowser a following bridge info:

```
127.0.0.1:5005
```

Using TorBrowser I opened a random website and checked the Tor Circuit info and it tells me that indeed my first hop is a "Bridge" (I assume, it's my Chutney bridge). But next hops are real Tor Nodes out in the wild, not the test nodes in my network! I surely didn't expect that.

So, why is my Chutney network connecting to the main Tor network (or it seems so to me)? Can I prevent that and use only my local network to access the internet through it?

Comment: Did you start the tor client with Chutney, and tell the Tor Browser to use that tor client? If the Tor Browser's tor client doesn't know it should be using a Chutney network, it will build circuits through the real network instead.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that: started Tor client with Chutney, opened TorBrowser and entered bridge info. So then:
1. Can I tell TorBrowser to use one of the Chutney's clients or tell it in some other way to use Chutney?
2. Meanwhile, I tried editing TorBrowser torrc file and added DirAuthorities from the Chutney network, but this way TorBrowser won't connect to Tor at all. I assume it's because Chutney network is configured to be a test network, so is it a worth path to follow?
At the end, my goal is just to route real internet traffic through Chutney network, I am not sure if it's realistic.

Comment: By default the Tor Browser uses its own tor client, so this client won't know about your Chutney network. You can tell Tor Browser to use a different tor client (open the `tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser` script and look for the `Using a system-installed Tor process with Tor Browser` comment). Try following this guide and setting the options to use one of your Chutney clients.

Comment: It's nice to know that there is such an option, but I can't find mentioned starting script. I am using macOS, which I probably should've mentioned before. I've spent some time trying to achieve my goal by trying to modify TorBrowser torrc file in a way to make it look alike chutney clients, but had not been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Ah I'm not sure about MacOS and how they package their apps, on Linux it's [this file](https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git/tree/RelativeLink/start-tor-browser). I *think* you should be able to do the same thing by editing the browser's torrc directly. I would start the chutney network, look at a torrc file it generates for one of its clients, copy the contents to your browser torrc file, and modify the ports and data directory paths to values not used by other Chutney nodes. The tor browser will also need access to the client's control port.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I am trying to go now, modifying torrc file to make it alike Chutney client torrc file. With all the ports set to previously unused values, I am stuck now at "Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.". I can see a lot of people suggest that this message means there might be something wrong with my timezone, but it seems fine to me. I will try to post some kind of update if I succeed